# Trying to copy a file from the current directory to F:\ drive in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Here's what I have so far:

```
If E = 1 Then
obj.CopyFile "(CD.CurrentDirectory)" "E:\"
End If
```

(My WScript variable is CD)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add _properly formatted_ [mcve]. Note that **Trying to copy a file** is not an answerable question in _any_ sense.

Comment: `FileSystemObject.CopyFile "*.doc", "E:\"`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a path the FileSystemObject will look in the current directory.

```
Dim fso

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

fso.CopyFile "text.txt", "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverflow\"
```

It worth noting that you can give the new file a different name.

> fso.CopyFile "text.txt", "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverflow\testing123.txt"